# footer - как правильно прописывать ссылки

Tags: html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
подскажите пожалуйста как правильно прописывать ссылку и поставить палочку между ссылками )

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: палочку можно поставить символом `|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разделитель (палочку) можно поставить так:

```html
<footer>
  <a href="#">Служба поддержки</a> | <a href="#">Политика конфиденциальности</a>
</footer>
```

Это всего лишь пример, так что вы можете доработать его под себя.